# Change font-size by nth line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, fonts

So, I have a JSON feed of names which I'm putting into span elements (can change element or remove entirely).

I have a design that requires the font-size get smaller as the list of names goes on, on a per line basis. So the top line of names will be say 3rem, the next line 2.5rem, etc. The text will be justified within its container. Think star wars intro text, but font-size not perspective.

It has to be dynamic in that the names could shuffle around. Does anyone know a javascript solution that could find how many names fit onto the first line with a given font-size, wrap them and move onto the next line and repeat with a smaller size?

Hopefully this is somewhat clear, it's an angular (ng-repeat) build if that helps at all.

If only we had an nth-line selector!

Example of layout:

```
Name - Name - Name <=3rem
Name - Name - Name - Name <=2rem
Name - Name - Name - Name - Name <=1rem
```

But justified.

Or Imagine each letter as a word!

[image: imagine each letter as a word]

Comment: A pure CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3tqeg8qh/ , doesn't know if that works in your case though. The auto-wrapping part is too advanced to handle purely in CSS, so JS might be necessary if you really want to go into that design.

Comment: Yeah that works great for span per line, however I've got multiple spans per line, so unfortunately that won't work for me.

Comment: It would be much easier if you showed us some of your actual code :)

Comment: how about some combination of css 3d transforms? but i'm not sure how exactly how that would be executed...

Comment: Joshua, I don't have any code yet. I'm simply planning how I'm going to approach this. Right now all I have is a big list of names via JSON.

danyamachine, I just tested that idea, doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: haha ok here's an illustration of what i had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/kohbn9jq/. it's pretty silly. in short: a parent element with rotateX(-50deg), and children elements with rotateX(50deg). there are a lot of problems with that approach tho :)

Comment: nice! although then I'd have big issues justifying it :) nice though! Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// long array of “names” (just lorem ipsum words here)
var names = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.'.split(' ');

var container = $('#container'),
    offsetTop = newOffsetTop = 0,
    fontSize = 3;

for(var i=0, l=names.length; i<l; ++i) {
    var span = $('<span/>').text(names[i]+' ');
    container.append(span);
    newOffsetTop = span.position().top;
    if(newOffsetTop > offsetTop) {
        fontSize *= .9;
    }
    span.css('font-size', fontSize+'rem');
    offsetTop = newOffsetTop;
}
```

```css
#container {
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;
    text-align:justify;
}
#container:after {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

How it works:

The words (names, whatever – supply your own array) are appended to the container element one at a time. For each newly added element, its top offset within the parent element is measured – if that is higher than the one of the previous element, that means the browser has pushed the new element onto the next line, because there wasn’t enough space any more on the current line. In that case, we decrease the font size. (Notice that I have done that here by multiplying the current font size by a factor of `.9`, otherwise the size gets too small too quickly. Feel free to adapt to your needs.)

A space is added to each word inside its span as well – otherwise we would just get one long line of text, that would not break automatically. (And we can’t float the spans here, because we want them justified.)

The after pseudo element with `display:inline-block` and a width of 100% is a nifty little trick to get the last actual line of text to be justified as well; without that, the words on the last line would just get left-aligned. ([`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last#Browser_compatibility) doesn’t have enough browser support as of now for my taste, so I prefer this solution. It causes an additional empty line at the end of the container element – if that is unacceptable, that could be avoided by calculating the correct height for the container element via script as well.)

Now of course if you want to shuffle the names, you’d have to run this whole thing again. And also if the width of the container element changes (so in some kind of responsive layout, you’d want to set up a resize event handler for this.)

(Also as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubnugdtv/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks perfect! One small question, will it work with multiple word names? I don't have time to test this evening, however I will try it for sure this weekend! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You mean names that include spaces? Those might break between words, so that part of the span might be on one line and part of it on the next. Easiest to avoid, if you replace those spaces by a non-breaking space. Alternatively, you could also make the spans `display:inline-block` – but then you would have to append the space character that I included in the span’s text content _after_ each span (otherwise you’ll get no space between the names.)